# how to insert multiple row in one table according to single row of another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 2 tables, `tr_testmodule` and `TR_Modulelocationdtl`.

```
select * from tr_testmodule -output like below (nmoduleno is primary key, vlocationno is varchar)

    nmoduleno   vlocationnno          
    1           3,65,6,9,63        
    2           13,625,62,91,613
```

Now I want to insert data from tr_testmodule to TR_Modulelocationdtl for each row of tr_testmodule with only single query.

For example I want to insert a number of rows for single moduleno

```
select * from TR_Modulelocationdtl --(nid is pk,nlocationo-int)

        nid nmoduleno   nlocationno
        1   1             3 
        2   1             65
        3   1             6
        4   1             9
        5   1             63
        6   2             13
        7   2             625
```

i can split the data like this into temptable (but only for single row) from the temp table i can insert data into my 'TR_Modulelocationdtl'

```
SELECT * INTO #TR_Modulelocationdtl FROM (SELECT data AS nLocationno FROM dbo.SplitString('1,23,2,3,5',',') ) AS nLocationno
select * from #TR_Modulelocationdtl 

nLocationno
1
23
2
3
5
```

Comment: insert into t1 (col1, col2, ...) select cola, colb, ... from t2 where ...?

Comment: Now I see, unpivot. Good idea, because comma separated items is a mess and only cause lots of problems - as I guess you have just noticed.

Comment: @jarlh can you write query for me with the use of unpivot

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (You'll probably need product specific functionality here.)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know SQL Server that well.

Comment: It may be easiest to write a stored procedure rather than try to do it in one single SQL statement. But, I too, don't know SQL Server well enough to write such function quickly.

Comment: not a problem @jarlh .have a good day..

Comment: ok @ThorstenKettner no problem .
but i just edited my question.so if u can get any idea from that then comment plz

Comment: Is it something you want to do once, or something you need to do regularly ?

Comment: I want to do it regularly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( n INT, v VARCHAR(100) )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, '3,65,6,9,63' ),
        ( 2, '13,625,62,91,613' )


SELECT  n, s
FROM    @t
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS s
                      FROM      ( SELECT    CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(v, ',','</M><M>')
                                                  + '</M>' AS XML) AS s) AS A
                      CROSS APPLY s.nodes('/M') AS Split ( a )
                    ) ca
```

Output:

```
n   s
1   3
1   65
1   6
1   9
1   63
2   13
2   625
2   62
2   91
2   613
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something rather easy to solve with a stored procedure (or an anonymous block for that matter): Loop through the records currently in tr_testmodule, split vlocationnno and loop through the locations thus got, then insert into tr_modulelocationdtl.

I don't know SQL Server well enough, so here is an equivalent Oracle script that can serve as pseudo code. It should be rather easy to convert it to SQL Server I guess.

```
begin
  for rec in (select * from tr_testmodule) loop
    for loc in (select to_number(column_value) as nlocationno from xmltable(rec.vlocationnno)) loop
      insert into tr_modulelocationdtl (nmoduleno, nlocationno)
      values (rec.nmoduleno, loc.nlocationno);
    end loop;
  end loop;
  delete from tr_testmodule;
  commit;
end;
```

Comment: As i have to convert this into sql server code,i will do it in free time and if any query then let you know .

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into TR_Modulelocationdtl (nmoduleno,nlocationno,vlocationcode,dmodifyon)(

SELECT  nmoduleno, nlocal,PlaceMst.vCityCode,GETDATE()
FROM    tr_modulemst
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS nlocal
                      FROM      ( SELECT    CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(vlocationno, ',','</M><M>')
                                                  + '</M>' AS XML) AS vlocationno) AS A
                      CROSS APPLY vlocationno.nodes('/M') AS Split ( a )
                    ) ca 

                    left join PlaceMst
                    on PlaceMst.nCityNo = nlocal
                    )
```